# Numeric Specifier for prefixing single digit with 0

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I need to numeric format specifier, so as to prefix single digit with 0.

**I need:**

```
1=01
2=02
:
:
:
9=09
```

The two and three digits will remain as it is no changes

```
10=10
11=11
:
:
```

Comment: Like this: http://ideone.com/nfYuNQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
int nr = 1;
var result = nr.ToString("00");
```

`result` will be "01"

Answer (score 1):

Use the PadLeft method for that

```
int number = 9;
string num = number.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

if your language is C# then you can use PadLeft(2, '0');
as like `string a= '1'
string b= a.PadLeft(2, '0')` you answer will show 01
if need 1=001 then just use PadLeft(3, '0');